# How to bind angular-ui directive $scope with my controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I know, angular-ui directives creates it own scope that is separate from my own. But i want to manipulate data from my template. For example: I want to use angular-ui popover (or modal) which will show some info when user click on some element on the page. Which the best way to bind angular-ui with my data?

**Edit**

For example:
I have a model like this:

```
$scope.countries = [
    {name: 'France', population: 63.1},
    {name: 'United Kingdom', population: 61.8},
    {name: 'Germany', population: 45.8}
]
```

And in view i have ng-repeater something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
      name:{{country.name}} 
      population: {{country.population}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

When user click on any "li" item i want to show popover with data form choosed item

Answer (score 0):

You can't access isolated scope's properties directly. You shall manipulate with options provided, for example popover has `popover-is-open` option. bind your controller's scope variable to it and then change it:

```
<button popover="{{dynamicPopover.content}}" popover-is-open="isOpen" type="button">
```

EDIT:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries" popover="name:{{country.name}} population: {{country.population}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```